# Two datasets rescaled and combined into one

Tags: r

I need to rescale two sets of variables: 1 that goes from -2.5 to 2.5 and another one that goes from 0 to 1 into 1:10 with set mean and SD (common) mean = 2 and SD = 4.5 using R. Can anything help? Thanks in advance!

I tried simple scale(x) formula to get z-score and then rescale(x) formula setting the new scale 1:10. However, I can't find a way to set the mean and SD to common values in rescaling, so the two datasets are comparable.

```
attach (WGI)
summary (WGI$PV_1996)
Vector1 <- c(WGI$PV_1996)
x<- Vector1

scale(x)

rescale<- function(x)(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) *10
rescale (scale(x))
sd (scale(x))
summary (scale(x))
dataout <-rescale(x)
print(dataout)

write.csv(dataout, file="RescaledWGI_1996.csv")
```

Expected outcome: combined dataset that includes two rescaled original datasets.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. -

Comment: please include your data in a copy-pastable way (eg using `dput(head(data, 20))` and adding the output to your question

Comment: polity_country Resc_PV_1996 Resc_Pol_1996
Afghanistan 0.64 0
Albania 5.58 8.21
Algeria 2.14 0.00
Angola 1.47 0.00
Argentina 6.63 8.41
Armenia 5.51 4.11
Australia 9.69 9.69
Austria 9.71 8.48
Azerbaijan 4.39 0.00

Comment: And I don't have an output yet, as I don't know how to achieve it.